# C++ invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, am trying to write a program that computes profit and tax for

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//FUNCTION PROTOTYPE - we are simply defining the function but the body function is in another file
int taxCalculator(int qnty[], int s_px[]);
int profitCalculator(int unit_selling_price[], int quantity[], int unit_buying_price[]);

int total_brands=0;
//MAIN FUNCTION TO CALL THE TWO FUNCTIONS
int main(){

    //Accept input variables
    cout << "Enter number of cement types that you have: " << endl;
    cin >> total_brands;


    //Define in put variables
    int quantity[total_brands];
    int unit_buying_price[total_brands];
    int unit_selling_price[total_brands];
    string brand[total_brands];

    for(int i=0; i<total_brands; i++){

            //accepting cement types
        cout << "Enter cement type name " << (i+1) << ": " << endl;
        cin >> brand[i];
        //for each cement type, we are accepting prices
        cout << "Enter the quantity of " << brand[i] << ": " << endl;
        cin >> quantity[i];
        //for each cement type, we are accepting prices
        cout << "Enter unit buying price of " << brand[i] << ": " << endl;
        cin >> unit_buying_price[i];
        //for each cement type, we are accepting prices
        cout << "Enter unit selling price of " << brand[i] << ": " << endl;
        cin >> unit_selling_price[i];

        //call the two functions
        taxCalculator(quantity[i], unit_selling_price[i]);
        profitCalculator(unit_selling_price[i], quantity[i], unit_buying_price[i]);

        cout << "SN " << "CEMENT TYPE" << " " << "PURCHASING PRICE/BAG" <<" " <<"SELLING PRICE/BAG"<<" "  <<"QUANTITY SOLD"<<" " << "TAX" <<" " << "PROFIT" << endl;
        cout <<i+1 << brand[i] << " " << unit_buying_price[i] <<" " <<unit_selling_price[i]<<" "  <<quantity[i]<<" "  <<tax[i]<< " "  <<profit[i]<< endl;
    }




     return 0;

 };

 //Function to calculate tax
int taxCalculator(int qnty[], int s_px[]){
    int tax[total_brands];
    int i=0;


    if(qnty[i] < 1500){
        tax[i] = 0.15 * qnty[i] * s_px[i];
    }
    else if (qnty[i] >= 1500 && qnty[i] < 3000){
        tax[i] = 0.20 * qnty[i] * s_px[i];
    }
    else if (qnty[i] >= 3000){
        tax[i] = 0.25 * qnty[i] * s_px[i];
    }

    return tax[i];
};

//Function to calculate profit
int profitCalculator(int unit_selling_price[], int quantity[], int unit_buying_price[]){
    int i;
    int tax[i]
    int profit[i] = (unit_selling_price[i] * quantity[i]) - tax[i] - (unit_buying_price[i] * quantity[i]);
    return profit[i];

}
```

but am getting below error

```
|=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
|In function 'int main()':| 40|error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]| 6|note:   initializing argument 1 of
'int taxCalculator(int*, int*)'| 40|error: invalid conversion from
'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]| 6|note:   initializing argument 2 of
'int taxCalculator(int*, int*)'| 41|error: invalid conversion from
'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]| 7|note:   initializing argument 1 of
'int profitCalculator(int*, int*, int*)'| 41|error: invalid conversion
from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]| 7|note:   initializing argument 2
of 'int profitCalculator(int*, int*, int*)'| 41|error: invalid
conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]| 7|note:   initializing
argument 3 of 'int profitCalculator(int*, int*, int*)'| 44|error:
'tax' was not declared in this scope| 44|error: 'profit' was not
declared in this scope| |In function 'int profitCalculator(int*, int*,
int*)':| 77|error: expected initializer before 'int'| 78|error:
'profit' was not declared in this scope| ||=== Build failed: 9
error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Your functions take `int` arrays arguments; you are passing them `int`s.

Comment: `invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'` means exactly that: you are trying to convert `int` to `int*`. A function, presumably, expects `int*` and you pass `int`.

Comment: Specifically, the line number cited in the first error message is line 40, which is `taxCalculator(quantity[i], unit_selling_price[i]);` where, as Scott, says, you are passing `int` arguments for `int *` declared arguments.

Comment: The code is using arrays when it does not need them.  Also, the code is using arrays incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You imagined your functions to work on the integer values you're passing them, but wrote them using the array syntax.

```
//Function to calculate tax
int taxCalculator(
    int qnty,
    int s_px)
{
    int tax;

    if (qnty < 1500) {
        tax = 0.15 * qnty * s_px;
    }
    else if (qnty >= 1500 && qnty < 3000) {
        tax = 0.20 * qnty * s_px;
    }
    else if (qnty >= 3000) {
        tax = 0.25 * qnty * s_px;
    }

    return tax;
};

//Function to calculate profit
int profitCalculator(
    int unit_selling_price,
    int quantity,
    int unit_buying_price,
    int tax)
{
    int profit = (unit_selling_price * quantity) - tax - (unit_buying_price * quantity);

    return profit;
}
```

Also you forgot to store the return value of the functions in `tax[i]` and `profit[i]`

```
int main()
{
    //Accept input variables
    cout << "Enter number of cement types that you have: " << endl;
    cin >> total_brands;

    //Define in put variables
    int quantity[total_brands];
    int unit_buying_price[total_brands];
    int unit_selling_price[total_brands];
    //----------------------------------------------
    int tax[total_brands];
    int profit[total_brands];
    //----------------------------------------------
    string brand[total_brands];

    for (int i=0; i<total_brands; i++) {
        //accepting cement types
        cout << "Enter cement type name " << (i+1) << ": " << endl;
        cin >> brand[i];
        //for each cement type, we are accepting prices
        cout << "Enter the quantity of " << brand[i] << ": " << endl;
        cin >> quantity[i];
        //for each cement type, we are accepting prices
        cout << "Enter unit buying price of " << brand[i] << ": " << endl;
        cin >> unit_buying_price[i];
        //for each cement type, we are accepting prices
        cout << "Enter unit selling price of " << brand[i] << ": " << endl;
        cin >> unit_selling_price[i];


    //----------------------------------------------
    // The function were called,
    // but the result was not saved
        //call the two functions
        tax[i] = taxCalculator(
            quantity[i],
            unit_selling_price[i]
        );

    // profitCalculator() was missing the tax parameter
        profit[i] = profitCalculator(
            unit_selling_price[i],
            quantity[i],
            unit_buying_price[i],
            tax
        );    
    //----------------------------------------------

        cout << "SN " << "CEMENT TYPE" << " " << "PURCHASING PRICE/BAG" <<" " <<"SELLING PRICE/BAG"<<" "  <<"QUANTITY SOLD"<<" " << "TAX" <<" " << "PROFIT" << endl;
        cout << i+1 << brand[i] << " " << unit_buying_price[i] << " " << unit_selling_price[i] << " " << quantity[i] << " " << tax[i] << " " << profit[i] << endl;
    }

     return 0;
}
```

Here is the working code: https://onlinegdb.com/bpLVXDflf